# Stuck on finding the 25 most common words in a text file

Tags: java, treemap

I'm stuck on finding the 25 most common words in a text file.

I have a vague idea how to do this use a `TreeMap` but i am unsure

```
public static String CommonElements(WordStream words){      
    TreeMap<String, Integer> Map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String w: words){
        w = w.toLowerCase();
        int token = Map.get(w);
        if(token != 0){
            Map.put(w,token);



        }
    }
}
```

The method is suppose to return a list of the most common 25 words in a text file.

Comment: Why a `TreeMap`? It's ordered by *key*, which is the string in your case, not the count.

Comment: Your `Map` is empty. You need to fill it first.

Comment: you should use a `LinkedHashMap` if you want to sort the map later by values

Answer (score 1):

## Code

Sample Code for the string `Stackoverflow could help you. Help Help at Stackoverflow.`

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class WordCount {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "Stackoverflow could help you. Help Help at Stackoverflow.";
        Stream<String> wordStream = Pattern.compile("\\W").splitAsStream(sentence);
        HashMap<String,Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        // foreach word count how many the word occurs in the wordstream
        wordStream.forEach((wordReal) -> {
            String word = wordReal.toLowerCase();
            if (!word.equals("")) {
                if (unsortedMap.get(word) == null) {
                    unsortedMap.put(word, 0);
                }
                unsortedMap.put(word, unsortedMap.get(word) + 1);
            }
        });
        // sort hashmap after value desc
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap =
             unsortedMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((v1,v2)->v2.compareTo(v1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                                      (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

        // just println word and wordcount, here you can limit to 25 (just delete)
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Word : `" + entry.getKey() + "` Count : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

## Output

```
Word : `help` Count : 3
Word : `stackoverflow` Count : 2
Word : `at` Count : 1
Word : `could` Count : 1
Word : `you` Count : 1
```

If you want to have only the 25 results you have just to limit the output after 25 results, or just delete all entries after 25 results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array of arrays,**Why becausee it will allow you to sort based on count**, where your sub array would contain two objects
    1. your words
    2. your count of occurences

```
//Sample object 
commonWords = [["most used word",20],["second word",15],...and so on]
```

Comment: Or... a `HashMap` and then use `max` on values.

Comment: @MarounMaroun how would you sort based on count using `HashMap`

Comment: You don't. You simply iterate on it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun then how do you get top 25 most used words?

Comment: Picking the keys for the max values is not really a problem.

Comment: Again you would need to filter these wherein above structure would automatically do it for you, sorting is required on both structures

Comment: Getting names for count would be a pain in hash map which isn't the case in array structure